# expect + change directory in expect script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcl, expect

We create the following simple expect script in order to run the `netdata-installer.sh`

**expect script is:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
send "cd /tmp/netdata\r"
spawn "bash netdata-installer.sh"

expect ">" { send "\r" }
interact
```

A few words about the `netdata-installer.sh`:

In order to run the - `netdata-installer.sh` , we need to run it from the working directory - `/tmp/netdata` , and this is the reason for me to use in expect the following:

```
send "cd /tmp/netdata\r"
```

Then in the expect script I use: (in order to execute `ENTER` , by this way we start the netdata installation)

```
expect ">" { send "\r" }
```

Until now, it seems things are perfect, but when we run the expect we get:

```
# ./exp.sh
spawn bash netdata-installer.sh
couldn't execute "bash netdata-installer.sh": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn "bash netdata-installer.sh""
    (file "./exp.sh" line 5)
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

It seems that the expect script does not change the working directory to `cd /tmp/netdata`

So where am I wrong?

---

**example when we do manual installation:**

```
./netdata-installer.sh

  ^
  |.-.   .-.   .-.   .-.   .  netdata
  |   '-'   '-'   '-'   '-'   real-time performance monitoring, done right!
  +----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--->


  You are about to build and install netdata to your system.

  It will be installed at these locations:

   - the daemon     at /usr/sbin/netdata
   - config files   in /etc/netdata
   - web files      in /usr/share/netdata
   - plugins        in /usr/libexec/netdata
   - cache files    in /var/cache/netdata
   - db files       in /var/lib/netdata
   - log files      in /var/log/netdata
   - pid file       at /var/run/netdata.pid
   - logrotate file at /etc/logrotate.d/netdata

  This installer allows you to change the installation path.
  Press Control-C and run the same command with --help for help.

Press ENTER to build and install netdata to your system >   <--- in this point we need to ENTER
```

Reference - https://www.ostechnix.com/netdata-real-time-performance-monitoring-tool-linux/

*Remark - the fact that when running the `netdata` we need only to give "ENTER" then maybe there  are other option to automate this installation ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we succeeded to automate the process as the following way ( not by expect  )

```
cd /tmp/netdata
echo -ne '\n' |  bash netdata-installer.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to build a software robot that can read text and press virtual keys, just ask the program to install non-interactively:

```
cd /tmp/netdata && ./netdata-installer.sh --dont-wait
```

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
spawn "bash netdata-installer.sh"
```

That takes `bash netdata-installer.sh` as a *single* value to run, *with the space,* and then can't find it. Unsurprisingly. You should pass that as several arguments:

```
spawn bash netdata-installer.sh
```

Comment: when I set - spawn bash netdata-installer.sh , I get the same results